# Math: How many combinations are there with 5 numbers?

Tags: math, combinations, permutation

I have checkbox form with 5 choices. The user can choose say #1,#3 and #4; or #1  and #2; or #2, #3, #4 and #5 and so on. How can i find out how many possible combinations are there?

Is it 5*5*5=125?

Comment: I think the answer will be `5!` = `5*4*3*2*1` = `120` ... this assumes that each checkbox is actually unique (i.e. that checkboxes #1 through #5 are all distinguishable as being separate from any other checkbox).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen that is only true if the order which the checkboxes are checked is important, ie checking box 1 after box 2 is different from checking box 2 after box 1.

Comment: The order doesn't matter.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Checkboxes are binary so you'll be able to represent any 5-digit binary number with 5 checkboxes.

The answer is `2⁵ = 32`

Answer (score 1):

```
1 number - 2 options
2 numbers - 4 options
3 numbers - 8 options
4 numbers - 16 options
5 numbers - 32 options
```

This is correct if we take into account the option when the user doesn't choose anything. If we don't then do -1 (for 5 numbers it will be 31).